# Hosting DD4T and traditional ASP.NET SDL Tridion application under one website in IIS

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, dd4t, iis-and-asp.net

I am  trying to configure **Website A** [ASP.NET MVC3 DD4T Website] and **Website B** [traditional Tridion ASP.NET 4.0 Content delivery website ] on `IIS 7.5`

Under IIS is there a way that we can host both websites **A** and **B** under same website (so that same port and domain name can be used) in IIS as different virtual directories?

We would need to have two different BIN folders for `cd_storage_conf.xml` file since it for website A it would query only from Broker and website B (May Query from Broker + FileSystem).

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Tarun

Comment: You could probably use .NET MVC Routes to deal with "content" under a given path differently?

Comment: Are you files in same publication for both sites?

Comment: no these files would be in different publication, DD4T websites(more than 1) will have different publicationa and standard ASP.NET webForm applications (more than 1) will have their own publication.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the setup? What routes/paths are you expecting to have to the various pieces of content etc?

Comment: I had previous applications on standard SDL Tridion Content delivery asp.net webforms application of extension .aspx or .html and also now I want to configure DD4T MVC application under same website in IIS, so is there any way that I can setup DD4T application under same website in IIS?

Answer (score 2):

We were able to configure our DD4T application :

1) Have separate Application Pool that parent Website.
2) Removal of Tridion Modules from the Child (DD4T Application) website.

By this, we were able to have different bin folder for having Tridion configuration files for DD4T than other standard Tridion applications.

Answer (score 1):

Nuno's answer points to a post on running ASP.NET MVC and WebForms side-by-side. There's a plethora of information out there on doing so, so I will skip that part of the question as it's not really Tridion-specific.

The crux of your question is this:

> We would need to have two different BIN folders for cd_storage_conf.xml file since it for website A it would query only from Broker and website B (May Query from Broker + FileSystem).

You're right to imagine that running two instances of cd_storage_conf side-by-side could get hairy (if it's even feasible). The good news is you shouldn't have to do that at all.

cd_storage_conf gives you the ability to change your storage based on:

- Publication
- Item type
- File extension

You could, for example, store .aspx files on the file system like so:

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
  <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".aspx" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
</ItemTypes>
```

Where `defaultFile` is the ID of one of your `Storage` elements. Or, you could get more granular and specify by Publication:

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
  <Publication Id="10" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".aspx" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
  </Publication>
</ItemTypes>
```

This should give you the flexibility you need and will mitigate the need for multiple "bin" directories.

You'll probably run into some bumps in the road at an application level; however, I see no reason why this couldn't work fine.

Comment: Thanks for this option, I would definitely try this option, so as in for such applications  I would have 2 deployers(DD4T + Standard Deployer) and a single bin for dd4T applications and Standard Tridion Applications.

Comment: There's no DD4T deployer - by default you'll just be publishing to the broker as normal. DD4T uses the normal Tridion content delivery stack so all you have to configure is what goes into the broker and what doesn't. Beyond that, this is just a .NET issue, which is well documented.

Comment: By DD4T deployer I mean deployer for DD4T based applications, since all DD4T deployer content(pages + CP) would go to Broker DB.

Comment: Yep - that would be the default Tridion deployer with your storage configuration pointing at the broker database as detailed above. You don't need a special/separate deployer for your DD4T content :)

Comment: But disadvantage of this approach would be that everytime a new website/publication is added we would need to make entries in cd_storage_conf

Comment: @TarunPanwar Not necessarily - if you use my first example, you can configure it globally so that .aspx files *always* go to the file system. If you need per-Publication configuration like my second example, then you can still specify a default configuration and just specify Publication config when needed. I'm not sure you're going to find another "approach" - if you want to host a single web application with both DD4T and Web Forms pages, you're going to have to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions will definitely try these and if it doesn't work then we might use different hostname as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

There you go: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Not much to to with Tridion... but fair question.

Comment: what difficulty we might face is to configure 2 BIN folders for these two websites in IIS since both of these applications will have different cd_storage_conf file, one to pickup content from DB and other to pickup from FS.

Comment: @TarunPanwar That's a pretty important detail, you should probably add it to your question.

Comment: Agree - I think that's the real question